# How to Pull the Second String (After Spaces) Using Regular Expressions?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have code that returns data that looks like:

```
['WKU  D02807750\n', 'WKU  D02807769\n', 'WKU  D02807777\n', 'WKU  D02807785\n']
```

I want to use regex in the loop that creates my list, which looks like:

```
import re
pat_nos = []
for line in open('file.txt'):
 if pat_no in line:
 pat_nos.append(line)
print(pat_nos)
```

so that it returns a list like:

```
['D02807750', 'D02807769', 'D02807777', 'D02807785']
```

I know I need to use the regex on the "line" when it is being appended, but I am not sure how to use regex to split everything between the last space after text (there could be 1 or two spaces after "WKU"), but the thing I want will always start with an alphanumeric character and it'll always end with a newline

Comment: You may not need regex for this if you're splitting on the last space. Just use `line = line.rsplit(' ', 1)[-1].strip()`.

Comment: @Abdou how would I get everything except the first element? So not splitting on the last space, more splitting and returning every element after the first. So if I had 'WKU  This is text that I want to return', it would return: 'This is text that I want to return' rather than 'return'

Comment: I think I got carried away by ***everything between the last space after text***. To me, that means splitting on the last space. But you may be able to split on "WKU" and keep the last element: `line = line.split('WKU ', 1)[-1].strip()` or use regex: `line = re.split("(?<=WKU)\s+", line)[-1].strip()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is guaranteed to be always the last substring in the string, you can simply use `split()`, for example:

```
lst = ['WKU  D02807750\n', 'WKU  D02807769\n', 'WKU  D02807777\n', 'WKU  D02807785\n']
result = [x.split()[-1] for x in lst]
```

output:

```
['D02807750', 'D02807769', 'D02807777', 'D02807785']
```

If it is not guaranteed to be last substring and you want to use regex, you can use something like:

```
import re
lst = ['WKU  D02807750\n', 'WKU  D02807769\n', 'WKU  D02807777\n', 'WKU  D02807785\n']
result = [re.search(r'(\w\d+)\n', x).group(1) for x in lst]
```

output:

```
['D02807750', 'D02807769', 'D02807777', 'D02807785']
```

Comment: This definitely works for this string, but for some reason, I am getting an error if I try it with code that returns something like (so a different leading string followed by a different following string (which also must be alphanumeric. 

['CTY  Bakersfield\n', 'CTY  St. Louis\n', 'CTY  St. Louis\n', 'CTY  St. Louis\n', 'CTY  St. Louis\n', 'CTY  St. Louis\n', 'CTY  St. Louis\n']

Is there something about the regex that I am missing?

Comment: The regex in the code above looks for one letter `\w` followed by one or more digits `\d+`, you need to change the digits part, `\w+` to look for letters or `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` to look for alphanumeric characters

Comment: And about your comment on Fabre's answer, you can use `[' '.join(x.split()[1:]) for x in lst]` to return everything but the first part =)

Comment: How would I allow for spaces to return 'St. Louis', not just 'Louis'?

Comment: If you want to use regex to skip only first part and include spaces, you can use: `[re.search(r'(\s.+)\n', x).group(1) for x in lst]`

Comment: or better yet, to remove the space from start `[re.search(r'\s(\S.+)\n', x).group(1) for x in lst]`

Comment: @JohnDoe Glad to help

Answer (score 3):

just build a list comprehension using `str.split()` and taking the last element

```
l = ['WKU  D02807750\n', 'WKU  D02807769\n', 'WKU  D02807777\n', 'WKU  D02807785\n']

print([x.split()[-1] for x in l])
```

note that linefeed is ignored since `split` is called without argument: splits according to 1 or many space characters (tabs, spaces, newlines...)

result:

```
['D02807750', 'D02807769', 'D02807777', 'D02807785']
```

(doing that using regex is more complex: `[re.split(" ",x)[-1].strip() for x in l]`, because regex split doesn't drop empty fields)

EDIT: another technique is needed if you want to return everything *but* the first item. You could `split()` and then `join()`:

```
[" ".join(x.split()[1:]) for x in l]
```

or yet limit the number of `split` operations (needs `strip` afterwards):

```
[x.split(maxsplit=1)[-1].strip() for x in l]
```

or you could use `partition` which splits according to the first space found, then `strip()` the result to remove leading & trailing blanks:

```
[x.partition(" ")[2].strip() for x in l]
```

with `l = ['WKU  D 02807750\n', 'WKU  D 02807769\n', 'WKU  D02807777\n', 'WKU  D02807785\n']`

you get `['D 02807750', 'D 02807769', 'D02807777', 'D02807785']`

Comment: Fabre how would I return everything except the first element? For example, if what I want to return has a space or a period? For example, 'WKU  D 05958513', how would I get that to return 'D 05958513' not just '05958513'?

Answer (score 1):

Because you wanted to use RegEx,

```
import re
l = ['WKU  D02807750\n', 'WKU  D02807769\n', 'WKU  D02807777\n', 'WKU  D02807785\n']
newList = []
search = '\\s(D\\d*)'
for thing in l:
    answer = re.search(search,thing)
    newList.append(answer.group(1))
print(newList)
```